# What is the name of this type of curve?

Tags: notation, terminology, curves

I encountered this curve in the notes for a physics experiment:

[image]

It was described by the equation
$$
A = \frac{kA_0}{m\sqrt{\left(\omega_0^2 - \omega^2\right)^2+(2\gamma\omega)^2}}
$$

Comment: I think it might be a bode plot?

Comment: It's not certain that there is an established name for this curve.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Why ever not? Do you mean you don't want OP to *only* ask the question in the title? (I agree with that advice.)

Comment: Answer to your comment: calling it a "Bode plot" is completely general, but doesn't describe this particular curve, which hasn't a name, up to my knowledge.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I see no call for that kind of derision for me. I asked an honest question, since we usually do want the title to be informative.